# Problems uploading a model in autodesk forge data visualization

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge

```
  forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app@0.3.3 dev
    > concurrently --kill-others "npm run watch" "npm run start" "nodemon 
server/localserver.js -- 
  delay 300ms --ext js,jsx"

[2] [nodemon] 2.0.7
[2] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[2] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[2] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,jsx
[2] [nodemon] starting `node server/localserver.js`
[2] http://localhost:9000
[0] 
[0] > forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app@0.3.3 watch
[0] > webpack --watch --config webpack.config.js
[0]
[1]
[1] > forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app@0.3.3 start
[1] > ws -p 9081
[1]
[1] Listening on http://DESKTOP-9P38L3U:9081, http://192.168.1.100:9081, http://127.0.0.1:9081
[0] asset bundle.js 23.4 MiB [emitted] (name: main)
[0] asset main.bundle.css 59.4 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
[0] Entrypoint main 23.5 MiB = main.bundle.css 59.4 KiB bundle.js 23.4 MiB
[0] orphan modules 80.9 KiB [orphan] 106 modules
[0] runtime modules 1.25 KiB 6 modules
[0] modules by path ./node_modules/ 8.37 MiB (javascript) 58.8 KiB (css/mini-extract) 1023 
  modules
[0] modules by path ./client/ 124 KiB 14 modules
[0] modules by path ./assets/images/*.svg 28.3 KiB
[0]   ./assets/images/fan-00.svg 2.66 KiB [built] [code generated]
[0]   + 11 modules
[0] modules by path ./scss/*.scss 50 bytes (javascript) 592 bytes (css/mini-extract)
[0]   ./scss/main.scss 50 bytes [built] [code generated]
[0]   css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?? 
ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[2]!./scss/main.scss 592 bytes [built] [code generated]
[0] modules by path ./shared/config/*.js 1.64 KiB
[0]   ./shared/config/SiteConfig.js 1.18 KiB [built] [code generated]
[0]   ./shared/config/ApplicationContext.js 474 bytes [built] [code generated]
[0] ./util.inspect (ignored) 15 bytes [built] [code generated]
[0] webpack 5.72.0 compiled successfully in 16688 ms
[2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[2] [nodemon] starting `node server/localserver.js`
[2] http://localhost:9000
```

this is the code i'm getting i followed this tutorial https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/quickstart/replace_model/
I'm trying to upload my own mode in autodesk forge but it doesn't work because when i go to localhost:9000/upload it reminds me to the default model of the reference app

EDIT: this are the errors in my browser console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
upload:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/viewer3D.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
this are the issues:
Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform
Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site context by specifying its SameSite attribute
Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute
also this appears:

```
{
"developerMessage": "Token is not provided in the request.",
"moreInfo":"https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling 
   /",
 "errorCode": "AUTH-010"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in your other question, make sure to follow the steps listed in the tutorial, specifically the creation of the *.env* file, and running the `npm run dev` command with the `ENV=local` env. variable.

Also, I've been working on a demo application similar to https://hyperion.autodesk.io that is much "leaner", using fewer dependencies, etc.: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-iot-extensions-demo. Feel free to give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm trying to use the demo application, but i don't know how to set up enviroment variables for the FORGE_CLIENT_ID and FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET. I'm using VIsual Studio code on windows.

Comment: Also it is possible that the command upload in the main application is not working because of scope execution policy? I've changed it to Unrestricted for the CurrentUser, but still not working. There are other thing i can check to make it work?

Comment: I think i setup my variables right directly from windows, but now the viewer is empty, without any model.

Comment: Please check if you see any errors in the browser console, and report them here.

Comment: i modified the question with the errors in the browser console. it shows also: Error: {}. Try logging again